# Can't seem to scrape off price from webshop in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to scrape of prices of products from different webshops.
I am doing this in `Python` with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`.

I want to scrape a price of a product but I don't see it come up in the output.

My code looks like this:

```
response = requests.get('https://www.fritz-berger.de/suche?q=8710315990829')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())
```

Normally I want to get the price with `regex` but i don't see it anywhere. I am missing something?

Comment: 1) you didn't show how do you use regex in your code 2) and by-the-way there is no products on this page 'https://www.fritz-berger.de/suche?q=8710315990829'

Comment: There is no regex (for now) because there is no price te regex. The link shows 1 product with a price. But somehow that doens't show in the output.

Comment: this link warns you `Es wurden leider keine Suchergebnisse gefunden. Bitte probieren Sie einen anderen Suchbegriff.` that mean `Sorry, no search results were found. Please try a different search term.`

Comment: Thats weird, i do get a result when i click on the link i mentioned (see image below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EDIT

You are using a specific setting concerning delivery to *NL* not *DE*, so it won´t find a result for a basic request to show up or redirect. So may try the XHR request to their search api and use `fv=NL` to specify:

```
https://search.epoq.de/inbound-servletapi/getSearchResult?full&callback=jQuery360016688827514037174_1673258199659&tenantId=fritz-berger-de&sessionId=c29bb0e240b3a0c61f643287bc3362d&orderBy=&order=desc&limit=30&offset=0&locakey=&style=compact&format=json&nrf=&query=8710315990829&ff=e%3Awhitelist_country&fv=NL&_=1673258199660
```

*This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus.*

---

Try to use a link or a relevant search term that is valid and leads to a product. Yours will lead to an empty search results page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.fritz-berger.de/suche?q=452210')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
soup.select_one('.current-price').get_text(strip=True).split('€')[0]

-> 5,99
```

Comment: Thats weird, i do get a result when i click on the link i mentioned (see image below)

Comment: Check the edit concerning your settings from the screenshot.